# failed ear file deployment on jboss server

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I'm trying to run a simple Java EE app on jboss `wildfly 8` server. I just by selecting `Run on Server` menu. but deployments folder is empty. browser shows `error 404 not found` by accessing address:`http://127.0.0.1:8080/EjbTest/`. Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out what problem my ear file had. As [EAR File Structure](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/ch01s04s02.html) says, my ear file didn't follow the structure. after putting necessary files into .ear file, it worked with no problem.